Trying to use an HTML form linked to javascript
When I'm trying my page, when I fill my form it instantly reload and nothing happen, I can see the glimse of an error in the console but it disapears instantly...
I have been trying to modify my form but nothing seems to work


// je gere la generation de nombre
function donneAlea(){
    nombre = Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1)
    return nombre
}
// je gere la banque
function management(somme,pari,victoire){
    if(victoire){
        somme = somme + pari
    }
    else{
        somme -= pari
    }
    return somme
}
// je m'ocuppe du bouton
let pression = document.getElementById('presse');
pression.onclick = function(){
    let baliseNom =getElementById('lenom');
    let nom = baliseNom.value
    let body = document.querySelector('body')
    body.innerHTML(`<p>test ${nom}</p>`)
    
    
}
console.log("test")
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Veux tu parier tout ton argent</title>
    <script src = "script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>La chance souris aux audacieux</h1>
        <p> Tu ne gagnes rien si tu restes sur le côté</p>
    </header>
    <main>
        <h2>Tu peux d'abord commencer par remplir es informations</h2>
        <form id ='formulaire'>
            <label for = "lenom" >Entrer votre nom</label>
            <input id = 'lenom' type = "text"  name ='lenom'>
            <button id='presse'>envoyer</button>
        </form>
    </main>
</body>
</html>




"I can see the glimse of an error in the console but it disapears instantly" - your browser console should have an option to preserve outputs across page loads, so go and enable that.

Your button is a submit button, but you did nothing to suppress its default action. So even if your JS function manages to change the page content momentarily, that will then get cancelled out by the form being submitted.

The main problem, which is causing the 'glimpse' of the error in the console, is that the button click submits the parent form. This in turn reloads the page, as you didn't supply a action attribute on that form. To fix this, hook to the submit event of the form element (not the click of the button) and call preventDefault() on the event that's raised via addEventListener().
Secondly, and this is likely the cause of the error you could see momentarily, you're missing the document. prefix on the call to getElementById('lenom').
Lastly, innerHTML is a property, not a method, so you don't call it with parentheses containing an argument - you simply set its value.
Here's working example with those changes made:


// je m'ocuppe du bouton
let formulaire = document.getElementById('formulaire');
formulaire.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let baliseNom = document.getElementById('lenom');
  let nom = baliseNom.value
  let body = document.querySelector('body')
  body.innerHTML = `<p>test ${nom}</p>`; // property, not method
});
<header>
  <h1>La chance souris aux audacieux</h1>
  <p> Tu ne gagnes rien si tu restes sur le côté</p>
</header>
<main>
  <h2>Tu peux d'abord commencer par remplir es informations</h2>
  <form id="formulaire">
    <label for="lenom">Entrer votre nom</label>
    <input id="lenom" type="text" name="lenom" />
    <button id="presse">envoyer</button>
  </form>
</main>




My answer is not different from the one above but just some additions. As explained earlier you are missing a preventDefault to prevent default action and document keyword on the getElementById.
Here  my changes
 <header>
   <h1>La chance souris aux audacieux</h1>
   <p> Tu ne gagnes rien si tu restes sur le côté</p>
 </header>
 <main>
   <h2>Tu peux d'abord commencer par remplir es informations</h2>
   <form id="formulaire">
     <label for="lenom">Entrer votre nom</label>
     <input id="lenom" type="text" name="lenom" />         <button 
 id="presse" type="submit">envoyer</button>
  </form>
</main>

And my javascript code is this
   document.getElementById('formulaire').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

 let baliseNom = document.getElementById('lenom');
  let nom = baliseNom.value
  let body = document.querySelector('body')
   body.innerHTML = `<p>test ${nom}</p>`
});

By explicitly setting type="submit", you make it clear that the button is intended to submit the form. This improves code readability and maintainability.
